# Is it possible to notify a staff coordinator for offline/backend contributions?

Tags: civicontribute, email

On online contribution page setup there is a the ability to send email notifications to different email address using CC & BCC. Using that, our coordinator receives the notifications for each donation submitted using contribution pages.

I am wondering is there a similar option for Offline/Backend contributions submitted by the users?  If not, is there any way to facilitate that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[CiviRules](https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.civirules) is available and you can use it to do what you want. There is [documentation](http://redmine.civicoop.org/projects/civirules/wiki) as well :-)

If you want to use CiviRules to send an email you will also need the send email API (and please pull the civirules branch): https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.emailapi

Once you have that you create a Rule, select the trigger for the rule as an event and come up with conditions. In your case the event will probably be 'new contribution' and the condition might be the source or the financial type, depending on how you are going to distinguish a back end contribution.

The action will then be 'send email', or could possibly also be 'create an activity'. It would make sense to me not to send lots of internal email but instead to create a specific activity type with a dashboard so the user can see his daily workload. But perhaps your end users have other preferences.

Comment: Thanks ErikH. I have managed to install it. But due to my limited knowledge I am not able to create an "action" to send emails. Would you be able to explain how to do it please?

Answer (score 3):

There is no equivalent option.  The presumption is that the only people entering offline donations are the sorts of people who would get notified.

This is probably something that [CiviRules](https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.civirules) (in development) might do for you.  It's also something that you could write in a custom extension using hook_civicrm_post.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Drupal then CiviCRM Entities should allow you to use Drupal Rules to do the required.

Comment: How to do it, can you explain a bit please?

Comment: I can't offer a recipe but the module is here https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity but am sure you could have found that yourself. You then need Drupal Rules module too. But it sounds like CiviCRM Rules is up and running so try that first perhaps.